# algorithm2e and \numberwithin with section

Tags: captions, algorithm2e

I am using the package `algorithm2e`, specifically `\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount]{algorithm2e}` to create the following algorithm:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount]{algorithm2e} 
\numberwithin{algorithm}{section}
%
\begin{document}

%
\section{Example of GA}
\label{sec_1}
\blindtext

\begin{algorithm}[h!]
 \KwData{The fitness function $f$, a stop criterion.}
 \KwResult{An approximation of $f^{*}$ and the point where is attained. }
\textbf{Initialization}\;  
 \begin{enumerate}[(a)]  
 \item $\mathrm{ExitLoop}\leftarrow \mathrm{false}$.
 \item Generate an initial population $P$.
 \item Evaluate the fitness at each point of $P$.
 \item Best point selection on $P$, $p^{*}\leftarrow \arg \min\{f(p):p\in P\}$, and its value $f(p^{*})$. 
 \end{enumerate}
\nl \textbf{Loop}\; 
   \While{$\mathrm{ExitCondition}= \mathrm{false}$}{
\nl\textbf{Update the population}\;
\begin{enumerate}[(a')]  
 \item Using selection, crossover and mutation prefixed rules, generate \newline a new population $P'$
 \item $P\leftarrow P'$.
 \item Compute  $p^{*}$ and $f(p^{*})$ as in (d). 
 \end{enumerate}
\nl \textbf{Decision}\;
  \If{stop criterion is attained}{
   $\mathrm{ExitLoop}\longleftarrow \mathrm{true}$\;
   \Return{$p^{*}$ and $f(p^{*})$}\;
   } 
 }
 \caption{General scheme of a GA}
 \label{alg_1_10}
\end{algorithm}
 %
\end{document}
```

The Algorithm is correctly generated, but the caption shows "**Algorithm 1: General scheme of a GA**", instead of "**Algorithm 1.1: General scheme of a GA**", which is what I want.

The command `\numberwithin{algorithm}{section}` generates the following error:

`! LaTeX Error: No counter 'algorithm' defined.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \numberwithin{algorithm}{section}`

What is going wrong?

Comment: please always post a small complete document that shows the problem so people can run it and debug the issue. It is much harder to debug a disconnected fragment.

Comment: Ok David Carlisle, added the complete document. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: Solved!!  The solution is to add the option  algosection in the usepackage algorithm2e:   "\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,noresetcount,algosection]{algorithm2e} "

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments